How to pass feature value to custom loss in Keras
I am using a custom loss to train my model and want to use feature value to have a differential loss, something like
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred, feature_val):
    return (feature_val ** 2) * abs(y_true - y_pred)

How can I achieve this in Keras?

maybe ask on similar portals DataScience  or CrossValidated or Artificial Intelligence

Hi @neel, If you want to use additional features in the loss function in Keras, this cannot be handled in a normal way as the other standard loss functions. Keras loss functions are intended to accept only two arguments – the true and the predicted values. If you want to add additional feature values to the loss function you can do so by creating a new class Keras Loss or Lambda layer.
